# How to fix "cannot use instance member 'textField_1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"?

Tags: initialization, runtime-error, self, swift5

My compiler doesn't show any problems but at runtime, I get an unknown error. I'm trying to place textField string input into a double array. Not sure what is wrong can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Haven't really tried anything but I think I have to use lazy syntax somehow.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
//  Outlets
//  textFields
@IBOutlet weak var textField_1: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField_2: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField_3: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField_4: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField_5: UITextField!

//  labels  
@IBOutlet weak var label_1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label_2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label_3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label_4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
//  Variables
var input : String = "0";
var a = 0
var age = "9.5"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //   Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
var numbers : [Double] = [90, 0, 0, 0, 0];  // where textfields will be converted to double
var userinput : [String?] = [textField_1.text, textField_2.text, textField_3.text, textField_4.text, textField_5.text]!; // textField storage

//  Button
@IBAction func button ()
{
    //   loop inserts userinput into numbers array
    while (a < 3) {
        numbers.insert(convert_to_double(input1: userinput[a]!) ,at: a)// inserts userinput after
        a += 1 // stops loop and changes array index
    }
}
//   converts strings to double
func convert_to_double(input1: String) -> Double
{
    let input0 : Double? = Double(input1);
  return input0!
}
}
```

:0: error: cannot use instance member 'textField_1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daTzV.png)

Comment: var userinput : [String?] = [textField_1.text, textField_2.text, textField_3.text, textField_4.text, textField_5.text]; // textField storage
Replace this code into viewDidLoad()

Comment: didn't work. Did you give it a go because it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the user's input with an index value.  Creating an array of text input values has two problems:

1. In your case, you can't create this array with a property initializer because `self` is not available until *after* the class has been fully initialized.
2. Creating an array of the user inputs will be static and won't show the latest values of the `UITextField`s if the user updates one before pressing the button.

You can handle this in one of two ways.

---

**Use a computed property:**

If you turn `userinput` into a *computed property*, then it will always return an array with the latest values:

```
var userinput : [String?] { return [textField_1.text, textField_2.text, textField_3.text, textField_4.text, textField_5.text] }
```

The downside is that every access of `userinput` will recreate this array which is a bit inefficient, but it ensures the array contains the latest values.  You can assign this to a local variable at the top of `button` to avoid recreating the array in the loop:

```
@IBAction func button ()
{
    let userinput = self.userinput

    //   loop inserts userinput into numbers array
    while (a < 3) {
        numbers.insert(convert_to_double(input1: userinput[a]!) ,at: a)// inserts userinput after
        a += 1 // stops loop and changes array index
    }
}
```

---

**Create a `lazy var` of the `UITextFields`:**

Create a `lazy` array of the `textFields`.  This array will be created the first time it is accessed, but since it contains objects, you will always have access to the latest input values from the user.

```
lazy var textFields = [textField_1!, textField_2!, textField_3!, textField_4!, textField_5!]
```

and then change your `button` loop to use `textFields[a].text!` instead of `userinput[a]!`:

```
@IBAction func button ()
{
    //   loop inserts userinput into numbers array
    while (a < 3) {
        numbers.insert(convert_to_double(input1: textFields[a].text!) ,at: a)// inserts userinput after
        a += 1 // stops loop and changes array index
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `convert_to_double(input1: str)` is equivalent to `Double(str)!`, so it doesn't add much.  You should avoid force unwrapping things which are out of your control.  You can use the *nil coalescing operator* to provide a default in the case that the user input doesn't covert to a `Double`:  for example `Double(textFields[a].text!) ?? 0`.

Comment: convert_to_double(input1: str)  it made no sense like you said but in my defense i was going to add more code to check if certain characters were type. I did end up using  Double(textFields[a].text!) ?? 0  . Thanks . Now i'm trying to print the doubles inside numbers

Comment: @Pep3, did this answer your question? If so, please accept it by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left to turn it green.

Comment: Thank u very much! it did but if u have time can u also show me how I would go about updating some labels or just printing out numbers to make sure the textfield input go converted to a double and then placed into the numbers array.

Comment: You can add print statements at key points in your code and they will print to the console. Also, you can set breakpoints and view the progress of your code step by step.

Comment: I did: print(numbers[a]) on top of a+=1 but it sometimes crashes the app or says something about Init can’t something or some thread error but I think with time I’ll figure it out. Not trying to bother you.

Comment: Search for the errors on Google and it will probably lead you to a helpful answer here on StackOverflow. You might want to consider using `append` to build your `numbers` array.

Comment: Ya trying different ways and googled different errors, I keep making progress but when I google errors it just makes me think about how much I don’t know about app development. Thanks again

Comment: There’s more to know than any of us will ever know. Keep plugging away. It gets easier.